# Can you help me to do this algorithm "Shifting a String to right or left"

Tags: c, algorithm, embedded, mikroc

I'm working on a project implementing a clock using PIC18, LCD, ... etc and I am using mikroC to implement this project.

However, I am not good at C and I am stuck at certain point. The clock has a menu with several options that will enable the user to set time, alarms, alarm sound, etc. The menu has the following:

```
1. Set Time
2. Add Alarm
3. Select Alarm
4. Add New Tone
5. Select Tone
6. EXIT
```

The clock has 3 pushbuttons, `OK`,`RIGHT`, and `LEFT`. When the clock power-on, it will show `Set Time` on LCD as default. I want to add a feature that when I press `RIGHT` pushbutton it should show `Add Alarm` but gradually not directly. I have 6 items in the menu so I have to do this gradually movement 12 times (6 for right and 6 for left). I have tried this as follows:

```
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "   set Time   ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "  set Time    ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, " set Time     ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, " et Time      ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, " t Time       ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, " Time         ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, " ime          ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, " me           ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, " e            ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "              ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "              ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "              ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "              ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "            A ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "           Ad ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "          Add ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "         Add  ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "        Add A ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "       Add Al ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "      Add Ala ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "     Add Alar ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "    Add Alarm ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "   Add Alarm  ");
 Delay_ms(50);
 Lcd_Out(2, 2, "  Add Alarm   ");
```

This was one movement and to do the others I need large code while the RAM of the PIC is limited. So, Can you guys help me solving this issue?

Comment: First things first: **you need a loop**. That immediately solves the redundant mess of code that you have now.

Comment: @Cody Gray: the problem is, how to shift the string either to right or to left?

Comment: How can I start a bounty for this question ?

Comment: You need to [wait 2 days](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#bounty).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here a variation avoiding all the `memcpy`, `str*cpy` orgy.

```
#define STRSZ 14

char str[STRZ*2+1] = "   set Time     Add Alarm   ";  /* The buffer must be writable */

for (i = 0; i <= STR_SZ; i++) {            // Loop
  char save_ch = str[i + STRZ];            // Save the character at the end 
  str[i + STRZ] = 0;                       // Terminate the string
  Lcd_Out (2, 2, str + i);                 
  str[i + STRZ] = save_ch;                 // Restore buffer
  Delay_ms (50);
}
```

EDIT: shift to right

```
for (i = STR_SZ; i >= 0; i--) {            // Loop
  char save_ch = str[i + STRZ];            // Save the character at the end 
  str[i + STRZ] = 0;                       // Terminate the string
  Lcd_Out (2, 2, str + i);                 
  str[i + STRZ] = save_ch;                 // Restore buffer
  Delay_ms (50);
}
```

On very small devices, avoiding unnecessary memory moves can be crucial

Comment: It works! really thanks ... can you please write the other part where it shifts to right?

Answer (score 6):

You need something like this:

```
#define STRSZ 14
//           <------------><------------>
char *str = "   set Time     Add Alarm   ";    // Two 14-char strings.
char disp[STRSZ+1];                            // Buffer for holding display string.
for (i = 0; i <= STR_SZ; i++) {                // Starting character to use.
    memcpy (disp, &(str[i]), STR_SZ);          // Copy the relevant bit.
    disp[STR_SZ] = '\0';                       // And null-terminate.
    Lcd_Out (2, 2, disp);                      // Display it then wait.
    Delay_ms (50);
}
```

For shifting the other way, simply use:

```
for (i = STR_SZ; i >= 0; i--) {
    // blah blah blah
}
```

If you're looking for a more complete example, try:

```
#define STR_SZ 14
// PreCond: from and to MUST be 14-character strings. EXACTLY!
// Pass in from and to strings and 1 to go left, 0 to go right.

void transition (char *from, char *to, int goLeft) {
    // Space for transition and display strings.
    char str[STR_SZ * 2 + 1];
    char disp[STR_SZ + 1];

    // Transition variables.
    int pos, start, end, incr;

    // Check preconditions.
    if (strlen (from) != STR_SZ) return;
    if (strlen (to) != STR_SZ) return;

    // Different values for each direction.
    if (goLeft) {
        start = 0; end = STR_SZ + 1; incr = 1;
        strcpy (str, from); strcat (str, to);
    } else {
        start = STR_SZ; end = -1; incr = -1;
        strcpy (str, to); strcat (str, from);
    }

    // Do the transitions.
    for (pos = start; pos != end; pos += incr) {
        // Copy string portion to display then delay.
        memcpy (disp, &(str[i]), STR_SZ);
        disp[STR_SZ] = '\0';
        Lcd_Out (2, 2, disp);
        Delay_ms (50);
    }
}
```

It's untested (other than in my head, which is *usually* pretty good) so you should consider it a starting point.

Comment: I tried this but does not wrok well. What does memcpy do exactly?

Comment: It copies memory. That particular one will copy exactly 14 characters starting at position `i` of `str`, with `i` going from 0 to 14 (left shift) or 14 to 0 (right shifting). It copies it to `disp` so it can be sent to the display.

Comment: it's just replacing `from` with `to` after some time without any shifting :\

Comment: @Eng: Then your Lcd_Out is not working as advertised, or you've mistyped the code (in particular, make sure the braces are correct). If your original code worked, so should this one, since all it's doing is rolling up the code into a loop.

Answer (score 2):

Most LCDs themselves support scrolling. So C libraries for LCDs provide functions for scrolling data. I have used PIC18 C library and it provides two functions

void lcd_scroll_left(char n) scrolls LCD screen left n positions.

void lcd_scroll_right(char n) scrolls LCD screen right n positions.

You can consult the documentation of the library that you are using for finding the function names you gotta use.

[Microchip PIC18 C library for LCDs](http://www.mastincrosbie.com/mark/electronics/pic/lcd.html)